# Split a string from followed character \r

Tags: python, python-2.7

7 on windows 7 and I got a *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10*.

What happened is, my output Power==0.00\r, (\r is hidden, so from output I actually cannot see it. I realize it from the following error) with the type string.

I would like to extract the 0 value as integer, so I converted Power as int(Power), then I got the error  *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00\r'*.

Any idea to split '0.00' from '\r'?

Comment: Try doing `Power = Power.strip('\r')` and then casting it to an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Antimony I try it out, but it comes out with same error.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has nothing to do with `'\r'`. You are trying to convert a string literal `"0.00\r"` into an integer number, but the number represented by the literal is not integer: it is floating-point. First,  convert the string to a floating-point number. Then, convert that number to an integer:

```
int(float(Power))
# 0
```

Comment: Just to confirm, so you mean a String can not be converted to an Int directly?

Comment: Not this kind of a string. But `"0\r"` can.

Comment: so the string (a number followed by character like \n, \r) is not able to convert to int, am i right?

Comment: As I said, it is not about `'\r'`. It is about the period `'.'`.

Comment: i see, so the string with format as '##.##' cannot be converted to int directly, correct?

Comment: That's what I said.